# Зацикливание запроса при неверном вводе Python

Tags: python, циклы, if, dict

Имеется задача по удалению значений и элементов из словаря.
Написал сам код который по вводимому значению ищет его и удаляет словарь в первом списке и элемент из значений во втором словаре.
Но хочу реализовать повторный запрос на ввод, если был введено значение которое отсутствует в этих словарях.

Вот сами словари:

```
documents = [
{"type": "passport", "number": "2207 876234", "name": "Василий Гупкин"},
{"type": "invoice", "number": "11-2", "name": "Геннадий Покемонов"},
{"type": "insurance", "number": "10006", "name": "Аристарх Павлов"}
]

directories = {
    '1': ['2207 876234', '11-2', '5455 028765'],
    '2': ['10006'],
    '3': []
}
```

Вот что я на данный момент родил

```
doc_del = input("Введите номер документа чтобы удалить его из каталога и убрать с полки: ")
  for docs in documents:
    if doc_del in docs["number"]:
      documents.remove(docs)
    
  for numb in directories.values():
    for i in numb:
      if doc_del == i:
        numb.remove(i)
      else:
        print("Введенный номер документа не внесен в базу, повторите ввод.")
```

Пытался делать и через while, но он как и в этом случае зацикливается на неверный ввод всегда, не зависимо от того существующее значение введено или нет.
Прошу вас, пайтон-джедаи, подскажите мне дилетанту где я обшибся и что делаю не так?

Comment: Вы используете, например numb в for и внутри for исправляете numb. Так нельзя. Используйте filter или map и получайте новый список

Comment: Я прошу прощения, если бред написал, но мое знакомство с пайтоном началось около недели назад. По условию задачи, я так понял, мне нужно редактировать именно исходные списки, в таком случае мне все равно надо создавать копии?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы реализовал вот так:

```
documents = [{"type": "passport", "number": "2207 876234", "name": "Василий Гупкин"},
             {"type": "invoice", "number": "11-2", "name": "Геннадий Покемонов"},
             {"type": "insurance", "number": "10006", "name": "Аристарх Павлов"}]

directories = {'1': ['2207 876234', '11-2', '5455 028765'],
               '2': ['10006'],
               '3': []}


def numDelete(doc_del: str):
    docs, dirs = [], {}
    changes = False

    for i in documents:
        if i["number"] != doc_del:
            docs.append(i)
        else:
            changes = True

    for key, value in directories.items():
        if doc_del in value:
            dirs[key] = [i for i in value if i != doc_del]
            changes = True
        else:
            dirs[key] = [i for i in value]

    return docs, dirs, changes


while True:
    doc_del = str(input("Введите номер документа чтобы удалить его из каталога и убрать с полки: "))
    documents, directories, changes = numDelete(doc_del)
    if changes:
        break
    print("Введенный номер документа не внесен в базу, повторите ввод.")
```

Не уверен, что лучшее решение, но работает как надо